# Hadith about Muslims who follow one Sunnah in 14th Islamic century

Tags: hadith, source-identification, sunnah

I read a hadith a long time ago which has a meaning similar to the following:

> In the 14th Islamic century when the whole world will be going in the wrong direction, if a Muslim follows one *sunnah* of the Prophet(saws), his status would be that of a Wali of Allah.

Can someone please provide me a reference to the hadith explaining similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer here..

http://islamqa.info/en/ref/89878

> “Whoever adheres to my Sunnah when my ummah is corrupt will have the reward of a hundred martyrs.”

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I have found are these hadiths

Abu Umayyah ash-Sha'bani said: I asked AbuTha'labah al-Khushani: What is your opinion about the verse "Care for yourselves".
He said: I swear by Allah, I asked the one who was well informed about it; I asked the Messenger of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) about it.

> He said: No, enjoin one another to do what is good and forbid one another to do what is evil.
>   But when you see niggardliness being obeyed, passion being followed, worldly interests being preferred, everyone being charmed with his opinion, then care for yourself, and leave alone what people in general are doing; for ahead of you are days which will require endurance, in which showing endurance will be like grasping live coals. The one who acts rightly during that period will have the reward of fifty men who act as he does.
>   Another version has: He said (The hearers asked:) Messenger of Allah, the reward of fifty of them?
>   He replied: The reward of fifty of you.

Daif(Weak) By Albani

http://sunnah.com/abudawud/39#51

---

Ma'qil bin Yasar (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said,

> "The reward of worship performed at a time of trials is equal in reward to an emigration to me."

[Muslim].

http://sunnah.com/urn/376260

---

Ma'qil bin Yasar narrated that the Prophet(s.a.w) said:

> "Worship during Al-Harj is like Hijrah to me."

(Sahih) At-tirmidhi

http://sunnah.com/urn/723560

Comment: JazakAllah brother. I am not sure but I think the one I am looking for might be a different one. However these were really helpful. I will keep researching and post it here If I find it.

Answer (score 0):

one sunnah would not be correct, it is greatest sunnah - invite ppl to Allah , 
The first pillar of Islam is to bear witness that, there is no God except Allah and I bear witness Muhammad is the Prophet of Allah. In order for this Great Kalimah to go into our heart we have to fulfil the right of the Great Kalimah. What is the right of this Great Kalimah? The right of this Great Kalimah is when we see disobedience to the orders of Allah or evils; we must forbid the evils by inviting peoples to good. We must start forbidding the worst of all evils. The worst of all evils committed by men is there do not want to bear witness that there is no God except Allah and to testify Muhammad is the Prophet of Allah. The best of good deed is to bear witness that there is no God except Allah and to testify that Muhammad is the Prophet of Allah. When a person recite the Great Kalimah, all his or her sins are washed away and converted to good deeds. A person who does not want to recite the Great Kalimah is known as non-Muslims and a person who has recited the Great Kalimah is known as Muslim. The second  most evils committed by men is, even though they had recited the Great Kalimah yet they do not convey the Great Kalimah to those who have not recited the Great Kalimah and the third most evils committed by men is, they do not perform five times prayers.